# TortoiseSVN (relocate to new repository)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-repository

We are facing a problem in relocating our application from the old repository to a new one.

Initially we were using `//10.X.X.50/svn/XXX`. Now we try to shift to the new repository at `//10.X.X.152:8443/svn/XXX` as the server hard disk has crashed (`10.X.X.50`).

While we are trying to use `relocate` option in TortoiseSVN - it gives an error:

> The repository at 'https://10.X.X.152:8443/svn/XXX' has uuid
>   '5005c752-e8bc-6a46-9f1b-84ec39085508', but the WC has
>   '005a1777-a2fa-4437-9a0c-b35647624529'

We are using TortoiseSVN 1.5.9, Build 15518 - 32 bit.

Currently, the new repository which is created on another server has three folders created: Branches, Tags and Trunk.

Answer (score 25):

You should either:

- Set the old UUID for your new repository, using [svnadmin setuuid](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.setuuid.html)

  - `svnadmin setuuid REPOS_PATH [NEW_UUID]`
- Or get a fresh checkout from the new repository.

If you go for the first option, when the new repository UUID's match the old one, just go to your working copy in Windows Explorer, right click in a blank spot and choose,

*TortoiseSVN → *Relocate...*, and there you will be prompted for the new repository location.

[image: Menu]

Then:

[image: New URL]

Comment: The OP states that they're trying to do that and getting an error.

Comment: I tried this because by project had been moved as part of a java.net move from Collab.net to kenaji but it failed its seems you need access to server which I do not have `:c:\Code\jthink\opensrc\jaudiotagger>svnadmin setuuid https://svn.java.net`/svn/jaudiotagger~svn 04e72293-3a78-0410-9da
svnadmin: 'https://svn.java.net/svn/jaudiotagger~svn' is an URL when it should be a path

Answer (score 2):

If you know what you're doing, just go ahead and edit the `wc.db` file by hand so that all instances of the old UUID are now the new UUID.

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to do this inside NetBeans using their subversion. I couldn't get it to work. Setting the UUID eliminated one of the problems, but not all.

I ended up going to Subversion server 1 and doing an svnadmin hotcopy command. Then moving it over to the new Subversion server and pasting it in the directory. This was simple to do, and it worked great.