# Tortoise svn relocate error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I try to relocate my project from one server to another. On new server this project already exists. When I start relocate I got the error:
 **The repository at 'https://XXX' has uuid 'yyy', but the WC has 'zzz'**

I use TortoiseSVN-1.6.12.20536-win32. How to solve this error?

Comment: Just to clarify - do you mean 1) you are moving where your subversion repository itself is held or 2) you are changing where your local client checks the code out from ?

Answer (score 1):

You should set the UUID of your old repository for your new one, using:

```
svnadmin setuuid REPOS_PATH [NEW_UUID]
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678272/tortoise-svn-relocate-to-new-repository) for more info.

Comment: Do I need this on the server or on the client side?